# Microsoft SQL Server insert from select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, insert

What I'm trying to do: read the logs and insert the necessary data into 3 different tables that get information from each other.

`LOG_ITEM201303` is found on gamelogs db.
`Mail_Item_Table`, `Mail_List_Table`, `Mail_Message_Table` is found on game db.

The Mail Tables are connected via the Indexes.

`CHAR_KEY`, `NAME`, `ITEMNUM` are the values I need to use for my queries.

The query for me to get the data from the logs:

```
SELECT CHAR_KEY, NAME, ITEMNUM
FROM LOG_ITEM201303
where 
(   
    ITEMNUM = 14317
OR  ITEMNUM = 14318
OR  ITEMNUM = 15478
OR  ITEMNUM = 15479
OR  ITEMNUM = 14301
OR  ITEMNUM = 14302
OR  ITEMNUM = 15476
OR  ITEMNUM = 15477
OR  ITEMNUM = 15018
OR  ITEMNUM = 15019
OR  ITEMNUM = 15020
OR  ITEMNUM = 15021
OR  ITEMNUM = 15022
OR  ITEMNUM = 15023
OR  ITEMNUM = 15024
OR  ITEMNUM = 15025
OR  ITEMNUM = 14437
OR  ITEMNUM = 14438
OR  ITEMNUM = 15656
OR  ITEMNUM = 15657
OR  ITEMNUM = 15658
OR  ITEMNUM = 15659
OR  ITEMNUM = 15660
OR  ITEMNUM = 15661
OR  ITEMNUM = 15662
OR  ITEMNUM = 15663
) AND (KIND = 133) AND (Convert(varchar, OCCUR_TIME,111) < '2013/03/22')
```

Sample result of logs query above(total actual results are in 600+):

```
 CHAR_KEY        NAME            ITEMNUM
 -----------+----------------+-----------
 28257      |   clarkailey   |   14438
 894367     |   Wolf         |   15023
 2869858    |   HOPEINME     |   14437
```

Now I need to automatically insert each row into this query:

```
 CHAR_KEY        NAME            ITEMNUM
 -----------+----------------+-----------
 2869858    |   HOPEINME     |   14437
```

(this query shows an example of the 3rd sample data above being inserted...
instead of making this query for each entry is there a way for this to done faster?)

```
INSERT INTO Mail_Item_Table
(ItemNumber, ItemInfo, ReceiveDate)
VALUES
(14437,       --this is the ITEMNUM
    (SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), REVERSE(CONVERT(BINARY(16), 14437)))), NULL)

INSERT INTO Mail_Message_Table
(Message)
VALUES
('Automated Message from the ADMIN.')

INSERT INTO Mail_List_Table
(ReceiverCharKey, MailListIndex, MailItemIndex, MailMessageIndex, Sender, Receiver, SendDate)
VALUES 
(2869858,       --this is the CHAR_KEY
(SELECT TOP 1   MailListIndex+1 as last_entry
 FROM           Mail_List_Table
 WHERE          sender = 'SENDER'
 ORDER BY       MailListIndex DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1   MailItemIndex AS last_entry
 FROM           Mail_Item_Table
 ORDER BY       MailItemIndex DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1   MailMessageIndex AS last_entry
 FROM           Mail_Message_Table
 ORDER BY       MailMessageIndex DESC),
 'SENDER', 
 'HOPEINME', --this is the NAME
 getdate())
```

My question:

How to automate all this, that the query will read all the logs and insert the data row by row. 
Thank you very much.

---

Can I use @variables for this?

Comment: select..into clause help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I'm looking into it. Thanks. [edit] Seem's like I can't make use of `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: Basically what you want to do is read data from LOGITEM201303 DB and insert data to the 3 tables you have mentioned, right? And data in each row (coming from LOGITEM DB) will go into these three tables as displayed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the following syntax for inserts

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Destination (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM dbo.Source
```

If you had tables with the same columns or a result set that had the same columns as your destination, you don't have to specify columns in the INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Destination
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Source
```

Both of these are predicated on your Destination table already being created.  These are **NOT** the same as `SELECT * INTO dbo.Destination FROM dbo.Source`