# insert from Multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, common-table-expression

I have query which looks like

```
with cte
(
code
),
cte1
(
code
),
cte2
(
code
)
select cte.1, cte2.1, cte1.2,cte1.3
from cte left outer join cte1 on cte.id=cte1.id
left outer join cte2 on cte.id=cte2.id
```

So my question how I can insert from this CTE?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600154/microsoft-sql-server-insert-from-select-query and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte.

Comment: just add insert into myTable between the CTEs and the select.(without the VALUES clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte
(
code
),
cte1
(
code
),
cte2
(
code
)
INSERT INTO TableName(Col1 , Col2 , Col3, Col4)   --<-- here
select cte.1, cte2.1, cte1.2,cte1.3
from cte 
left outer join cte1 on cte.id=cte1.id
left outer join cte2 on cte.id=cte2.id
```